# publish project error

Tags: winforms, clickonce

I have a windows form project and I want to publish it on the server using click once. It used to be working great. But today I got a message.

[image: message]

I have to click "No". Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you publish your project change the version to 1.0.0.56 at least. Make sure you're not overriding newer code.